# Cloudformation condition for string parameter length

Tags: conditional-statements, aws-cloudformation

In my cloudformation code (yaml file) I want to write condition that check if string parameter is longer than some value(lets say 15) and I did not find any way to do it.
Two main questions are,

1. How to get string parameter length?
2. After I have the length, how can I write condition that check if this length is longer/smaller than specific value?

I wish cloudformation has a Fn like LongerThan or something like this

```
 Conditions:
    isLongerThanParam:
        'Fn::LongerThan':
            - {Ref: Param}
            - '15'
```

But they only support these functions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this; as you've found, the intrinsic functions are quite limited. What are you trying to do? There might be another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: There is cloudformation limitation on bucket name "Bucket name should be between 3 and 63 characters long" and my bucket's name contains some constant prefix (with 48 characters) and the parameter `"Fn::Sub": "<prefix>-${Param}"`, so i'm trying to check if the parameter is longer than 15 and then use different prefix.

Comment: Would it be enough to set a MaxLength constraint on the parameter? That wouldn't allow you to use a fallback though; it would just stop the bucket name from exceeding the maximum length and causing an error.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it but I don't want to change the parameter name (which is used in other places) I want to change the prefix.

Comment: You could use the MaxLength as @PMah suggested but retain the original parameter, and a second `LongerThanFifteenBucketName`. Add conditionals `LongerThanFifteen`, and `ShorterThanFifteen` and the use `!If` to reference the correct parameter?

Answer (score 3):

> I did not find any way to do it

There is **no such functionality** in CFN. You already provided the link to available conditional checks, and there are no condition to check if something is greater or lower then something else.

Some possible **workaround** would possibly involve development of [CloudFormation macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html), which would be in the form of a lambda function. The function would take your `Fn::LongerThan`, and performed some transformations of it based on how you want it to behave. As an outcome of the macro, the valid conditions would be returned, whether or not `Fn::LongerThan` is satisfied.